# NSUserDefaults and read-only value

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, readonly

Is there a way to make some value of my preferences stored in the iPhone Application Settings to be read-only.
Let say that for some reasons I do not want the user to be able to modify some values.
Is possibile?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what `PSTitleValueSpecifier` is for.

Comment: I'm sorry, I really missed it from the documentation.
This is the link:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW11